# disable checkbox in angular tree component

Tags: angular-tree-component

I am unable to find any way to disable checkbox node using angular tree component.
There is no option to mark the tree disabled so that the checkboxes that appear alongwith th etree data should be disabled. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the node can be done by `actionMapping` inside options attribute https://angular2-tree.readme.io/v1.2.0/docs/options. Here click event of mouse can be overwritten.

```
<Tree  [nodes]="nodes"  [options]="treeOptions"></Tree>
```

In my **tree data** I kept an attribute `isSelectable` on each node, which is `true|false`. In case of true i proceed selecting the node otherwise it does not do anything. Here are full options that I am passing to the `tree` component.

```
public options: ITreeOptions = {
    isExpandedField: 'expanded',
    idField: 'uuid',
    getChildren: this.getChildren.bind(this),
    actionMapping: {
      mouse: {
        click: (tree, node, $event) => {
          if ( node.data.isSelectable ) {
            this.isNodeSelected.emit(node.data);
            this.alreadySelected = true;
            this.preSelected.tree = tree;
            this.preSelected.node = node;
            this.preSelected.event = $event;
            TREE_ACTIONS.ACTIVATE(this.preSelected.tree, this.preSelected.node, this.preSelected.event);
          }
        }
      }
    },
    nodeHeight: 23,
    allowDrag: (node) => {
      return false;
    },
    allowDrop: (node) => {
      return false;
    }
};
```